# Python pandas data frame output format

Tags: python, pandas, csv, format

I need to save data frame with specific format and i don't know how to change that format (or can it be changed that way).

I have `json`:

```
{
  'criteria A': {
    'topicA': [6, 2, 7],
    'topicB': [0, 6, 9]
  },
  'criteria B': {
    'topicA': [6, 4, 8],
    'topicB': [8, 6, 1]
  }
}
```

I have tried save my frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json)
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

But it saves array as cell value:

```
------------------------------------
|        | criteria A | criteria B |
------------------------------------
| topicA | [3, 8, 9]  | [6, 1, 0]  |
------------------------------------
| topicB | [5, 4, 9]  | [2, 9, 9]  |
------------------------------------
```

The only thing i want to change is *array* output and merge *criteria** cells to get something like this:

```
------------------------------------
|        | criteria A | criteria B |
------------------------------------
| topicA | 3 | 8 | 9  | 6 | 1 | 0  |
------------------------------------
| topicB | 5 | 4 | 9  | 2 | 9 | 9  |
------------------------------------
```

So criterias is 3 row wide and each array value placed in own cell.

Does *pandas* allows such formatting?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to format your columns manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the dataframe from the json which looks like below:

```
       criteria A criteria B
topicA  [6, 2, 7]  [6, 4, 8]
topicB  [0, 6, 9]  [8, 6, 1]
```

---

You can do something like below which creates a multiindex:

```
(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df[i].tolist()) for i in df.columns],axis=1,keys=df.columns)
     .set_index(df.index))
```

---

Output:

```
            criteria A       criteria B      
                0  1  2          0  1  2
topicA          6  2  7          6  4  8
topicB          0  6  9          8  6  1
```

Excel view:
[image]

Comment: thanks! now all values in their cells. but how did you merge criteria columns i your view? manualy?

Comment: @myTalala i didnt get it, i created the dataframe with the json you provided

Comment: yes, our jsons are the same, but "criteria A" appears for each index (0,1 and 2)

Comment: @myTalala ohh, no nothing manual here, `[pd.DataFrame(df[i].tolist()` <- this code takes care of it

Comment: so i did ```df2 = pd.concat(...``` and saved df2 ```df2.to_csv('test.csv')```. thats correct?

Comment: @myTalala yes, that is the idea here :)

Comment: i still got ```criteria A criteria A criteria A\n 0 1 2\n 6 2 7```. tried in google docs and libreoffice. even tried read raw cvs data. they sill apperas 3 times

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the columns to match that format you want and then save it. I am not sure if there is a way to directly save the data in list format into this ' | | ' format.

```py
import pandas as pd
json = {
  'criteria A': {
    'topicA': [6, 2, 7],
    'topicB': [0, 6, 9]
  },
  'criteria B': {
    'topicA': [6, 4, 8],
    'topicB': [8, 6, 1]
  }
}

df = pd.DataFrame(json)
df['criteria A'] = [' | '.join(str(el) for el in row) for row in df['criteria A'].values]
df['criteria B'] = [' | '.join(str(el) for el in row) for row in df['criteria B'].values]
```

An html view `df.to_html` looks like this.

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>criteria A</th>
      <th>criteria B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>topicA</th>
      <td>6 | 2 | 7</td>
      <td>6 | 4 | 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>topicB</th>
      <td>0 | 6 | 9</td>
      <td>8 | 6 | 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats a tricky one. I think your best bet would be to go for something like this.

```
------------------------------------
|        |CA |CA |CA  |CB |CB |CB  |
------------------------------------
| topicA | 3 | 8 | 9  | 6 | 1 | 0  |
------------------------------------
| topicB | 5 | 4 | 9  | 2 | 9 | 9  |
------------------------------------
```

Comment: yes, i got same result for now, but it will be much cooler if i can merge those cells. i think i will use default cvs lib and merge them via ir